# MLE for the mean of a small sample from a normally distributed population

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been reading through the chapters on point estimation and interval estimation from John E. Freund's Mathematical Statistic's with Applications and I have a question that I can't answer on my own. It's likely that I missed a detail in the text.

My question:

Let's say I have a normally distributed population, nothing is said of the variance, and I want to find a maximum likelihood estimator that a random sample from this distribution is less than a value $x$.

Would the best way to do this be setting up null and alternative hypothesis and then using the Neyman-Pearson Lemma, or would it be to find the maximizing function, $L\left(\theta\right)$, where $\theta$ is the value I want to compare the random sample too?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A *maximum likelihood estimator* is a function of your data that estimates the value of an unknown parameter in the distribution of your population. For example, let's you have a biased coin, and you're interested in estimating the (unknown) probability that the coin will land on heads on a single flip. You flip the coin $n=10$ times and observe exactly $X=2$ heads. Note $X\sim \text{Binomial}(10,p)$. The probability of observing this data is given by the following: $$l(p)=P(X=2|p)={10 \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^8$$

Comment: The value of $p\in [0,1]$ that maximizes $l(p)$ equals $\hat{p}=2/10$ which is your MLE for $p$. That being said, "the sample mean is less than a value $x$" isn't a parameter belonging to the distribution of your normal population that you can estimate using the techniques established by finding MLEs. Are you trying to estimate the *probability* that the sample mean $\overline{X}$ is less than $x$?

Comment: I think I phrased my question poorly. I will edit it after I finish this comment. So I want to see if there is a way to use the maximum likelihood estimate to test the probability that a random sample from this distribution will be less than a specific value. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they helped me clear up what I was actually thinking about doing.

Comment: Suppose you observe a simple random sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from a normal population with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$. Set $\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n}(x_1+\dots+x_n)$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-\bar{x})^2$. If you're trying to estimate $P(X<x)$ using MLEs where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ I think the most natural estimation would be $$P(X<x)\approx \int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{t-\hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}\big)^2}\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: In other words, use the MLEs for $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ to approximate your normal CDF.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I will try this and post what I discover. Thanks for the help.